# How to build branches from SVN in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using subversion and I want to make my jobs run on any branch of my choosing.  How do I define branch in pipeline so each job in the pipeline runs against that branch?

Comment: AFAIK only [github-branch-source](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin) and [bitbucket-branch-source](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin) plugins exist.

Comment: what about subversion

Comment: That's what I meant.. AFAIK the branch-source style is not yet available for subversion. Probably, because it uses the API of the VCS hosting services, instead of directly accessing the repos.

Comment: is there a way to pass a environment variable that can be used to pass to the jobs a parameter

Comment: not sure, what you mean.

Comment: what I want to do is define a variable in the pipeline and that variable is passed as an argument in each job.  That argument would basically be defining the branch [i.e. trunk, development etc..]